# how to make_pair includes weak_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to use `std::make_pair()` for `<weak_ptr, string>`, the error is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
.build/experimental_trusty/data_provider/Dataserver.cc:112:109: note:   cannot convert 'hdl' (type 'websocketpp::connection_hdl {aka std::weak_ptr<void>}') to type 'std::weak_ptr<void>&&'
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show the coding attempts you already made.

Answer (score 1):

You don't showed us your code but according to the error you posted, this is my guess.

Also, please research better. I've seen this very same problem several time in this site. And by the way, [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) has great example on how to use that function.

My guess is you have this code:

```
auto p = std::make_pair<websocketpp::connection_hdl, std::string>(hdl, str);
```

This is not the right way to invoke this function.

In fact, `std::make_pair`exists primarily for having template argument deduction. That is the mechanism of the compiler deducing what the template parameters should be according to the parameter sent to the function.

For example, if I write this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) {}
```

I can call it like that:

```
foo(4.7);
```

The compiler will deduce that `T` is `double`.

In your case, you should write this:

```
auto p = std::make_pair(hdl, str);
```

And let the deduction happen.